# Delphi 7: Enabling automatic list of possible options for items I am working on?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

I have recently started using Delphi 7 and am currently learning to make applications with it. I've read this while reading about the basics:

[image: The picture that the Delphi Basics website used as an example]

It says that Delphi helps us with a list of possible options for the item we are working on. Those possible options would help me a lot, as I currently have no idea what options there are, however, when I write, I get no possible options window, as shown bellow:

[image: What happens when I start typing]

Is it disabled by default, and if it is, where can I enable it?
It also may be important to mention that I am using Windows 10, and that Windows 10 does warn me that Delphi might not work properly with my Windows, although I sincerely doubt that's the reason behind this, as the whole program works just fine.

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for such a rookie question :)

Comment: 1. Try press Ctrl+Space after write "."
2. Install CnPack wizards

Comment: Buy a book :
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mastering-Delphi-5-by-Marco-Cantu/131625431605?_trksid=p2045573.c100033.m2042&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D33890%26meid%3D9ac71dfe79db4f81847ac21e3ebee23e%26pid%3D100033%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D261863124503

or 

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Delphi-5-Developers-Guide-Developers-Guide-/360945265947?hash=item540a03ad1b:m:mq6hYdXkPzTEONhH40K7F6g

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Living in Serbia, makes eBay obsolete to me, and finding books about Delphi that are actually worth reading extremely hard. That being said, I'd love to own a couple of books about Delphi and programming in general. Are there any other good and/or recommended books about Delphi out there?

Comment: @MilesRayne enlighten me please. What's the problem about buying a book on eBay when living in Serbia?

Comment: What about Amazon then? 

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/search/ref=a9_sc_1?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Amastering+delphi&keywords=mastering+delphi&ie=UTF8&qid=1445003344

Comment: @JensBorrisholt There have been tons of problems in Serbia with both eBay and PayPal, with deliveries never being received, money not returned and PayPal just simply not working properly for years. All of those problems should have been fixed by now, and probably are. Online ordering in this country is a story on it's own. I will try both eBay and amazon though, as hopefully, things have changed. But what the most important thing to me is, is knowing what to look for. Should I go for "Mastering Delphi" or go straight to "Mastering Delphi 7", as I'm only using that version?

Comment: You should go for Mastering Delphi 7 or Mastering Delphi 6 depending of which one (including postag)e is the cheapest.

Comment: Or even better: Go to the authors website and write him an eMail. Perhaps you can buy an online version of the book. explain your problems to him 

http://www.marcocantu.com/

Comment: Perhaps he could advice you about a book.  This one perhaps: 

http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Yeah, that sounds like a great idea, I will definitely see what the most viable option for me is, and get myself a book. Thank you for your advice and links. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called *Code Insight*. It's usually available automatically (the default is enabled).

You can find it in the *Tools->Options* menu in the IDE. It's also documented in the help file.

You enable *Code Insight* by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, either after typing the <kbd>.</kbd> or the first couple of letters of the property or type, as in

[image: Code Completion for Label1.Caption image]

Once the window is displayed, you can use the mouse or arrow keys to select the property or method you want to use. The most likely match is pre-selected (as you can see in the image), in which case you can just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept it.

There are other features of *Code Insight* that you'll find useful, such as *Code Completion*, *Code Parameter Hints*, and *Live Templates*, all of which are also described in the help file. Search for *Code Insight*.